# Reading values from vite.config.js in veltKit page/routes

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

So I have a `vite.config.js` file that contains a config object that looks like this:

```js
const config = {
.....
server: {       
        https: {
            //key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
            //cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
            key: tlsconfig.key,
            cert: tlsconfig.cert
        },
        port: 3031,
        proxy: {},
    
    }
}
```

This has been exported via `export default config;` line.

Is there a way to read/see the the values for the `key` and `cert` in a SveltKit page/route ?

### Update

So I was able to use `process.env.cert = tlsconfig.cert;` to set an environment variable that could be accessed using `dotenv` from a `+server.js` file located in my `routes/api` directory. I then created a `+page.svelte' file and used` fetch` to retrieve the variable.

Wondering if there's a better/easier way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the vite.config.js in +page.server.js and +server.js files:

```js
// src/routes/example/+page.server.js
import viteConfig from "../../../vite.config";

export function load() {
  return { 
    cert: viteConfig.server.https.cert
  };
}
```

```html
<!-- src/routes/example/+page.server.js -->
<script>
  export let data;

  console.log(data.cert);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - So I tried this but get an error when I try to import `__vite_ssr_import_2__.default.default is not a function`

Comment: Hmm, strange, worked when i tested it. Maybe there is an import in your vite config that' misbehaving (sometimes import * as Thing from 'thing' fixes it), you could also export the tlsconfig from a separate js file and import that in the +page.server.js